# J2ME for Nokia S60 5th: bluetooth serial API

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, nokia, s60

I think about writing a J2ME application for the Nokia 5230 which can communicate with other devices using a serial bluetooth connection. Is this supported on the Nokia SDK at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported by the Symbian Java environment. Take a look at [this example](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-D8E35189-340C-46DC-AD03-7811907418E0.html) for creating client/server pair using the bluetooth API, it is probably what you are looking for.